# Scala: branch instructions without var?

Tags: scala

What is the best practice when it comes to branch instructions in scala?

Lets say I have this code:

```
val initial  = Something(...)
val afterOp1 = initial.op1()
val afterOp2 = afterOp1.op2()
val result   = afterOp2.op3()
```

But now there are two options for op2: `op2a`, `op2b`

I can easily write the code with `var`:

```
val initial  = Something(...)
val afterOp1 = initial.op1()
var afterOp2 = Nil
if (useA) {
  afterOp2 = afterOp1.op2a()
} else {
  afterOp2 = afterOp1.op2b()
}
val result = afterOp2.op3()
```

But then I lose immutability. Another solution without vars is

```
val initial  = Something(...)
val afterOp1 = initial.op1()
var afterOp2 = Nil
if (useA) {
  val afterOp2 = afterOp1.op2a()
  val result   = afterOp2.op3()
} else {
  val afterOp2 = afterOp1.op2b()
  val result   = afterOp2.op3()
}
```

But this is obviously undesirable because I have to repeat code.

What's the best practice here? I have a feeling I'm overlooking something simple

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A nice property of `if-else` in Scala is that it is an [expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expression_(computer_science)), it returns a value.

Assuming `op2a` and `op2b` yield the same type, the simplest thing you can do is:

```
val initial  = Something(...)
val afterOp1 = initial.op1()
val afterOp2 = if (useA) afterOp1.op2a() else afterOp1.op2b()
val result = afterOp2.op3()
```

Answer (score 2):

Another way would be to use pattern matching:

```
val afterOp2 = useCase match {
  case useA => afterOp1.op2a()
  case useB => afterOp1.op2b()
}
```

That way you can support more than two use-cases.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure exactly what you want to achieve but you can process the whole if expression as follows:

```
val afterOp2 = if (useA) {
  afterOp2 = afterOp1.op2a()
} else {
  afterOp2 = afterOp1.op2b()
}
```

If you are talking about futures and success/failures then there are more elegant options